# Controlling the current through a Diode Bridge VCF

Tags: diodes, filter, bridge, synthesizer

I'm investigating different analog low pass filter circuits and came across this [Yamaha patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US4039980?dq=yasuo+nagahama&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZMsnVc3QCMvFsAWsxIHwBA&ved=0CFUQ6AEwCA) which ingeniously utilizes a diode bridge as a variable resistor. It takes some reading but in short: several transistors (Tr2-Tr5) act as a current source to provide a constant high impedance current to the diodes (from 'a' to 'b'). The relationship between the current through the diodes and the voltage across them results effectively in a resistance value. A signal is passed through the midpoints of the diode bridge ('c' and 'd') and and the effective resistance works with the capacitors impedance to filter out high frequencies in the signal. But having figured out how it works I'm not sure the current mirror/current source assemblage is really necessary. Could you not simply connect, say, Vcc to point 'a' and connect 'b' to ground? Couldn't you even leave in Tr4 between 'b' and ground and program it by sending a voltage to it's base?
[image: The circuit]

Comment: Connecting VCC to point a and point b to ground will let the smoke out of your diodes. (Assuming Vcc > around 1.4V.)  The current source (which is high impedance, not low) is necessary to bias the operating point of the diodes.  I would think this LPF scheme would introduce some distortion for anything but very small signals.

Comment: @JohnD Hmm, yeah, that makes sense. What if I were to eliminate Tr3 and Tr5 and replace Tr2 with an NPN transistor(and removing VR1). would the remaining configuration work?

Comment: @JohnD ...And yes, when I tested a similar diode bridge configuration I _may_ have noticed some distortion.

Comment: @JohnD AFAIK all analog VCF topologies that exploit the variable dynamic resistance properties of semiconductor junctions at different currents cause large signal distortion to some degree

Answer (score -1):

As a matter of fact current does not flow through the semiconductor diode but a mirror current exchanged at the depletion (P-N) region. The currrent in the depletion region changes the width thereof and hence its capacitance. Similar phenomenon means depletion region capacitance variation is also observed when the junction s reverse biased. Thus the junction capacitance is contrlled by the biasing voltage or current so the knee point of the filter.
V T Ingole